# Android, зацикливание анимации в objectAnimator

Tags: android, android-animation

Делаю простую двухсекундную анимацию: чёрная рамка за одну секунду желтеет, за вторую секунду возвращается к чёрному цвету.

Анимация работает, но у меня никак не получается её зациклить. Либо не зацикливается, либо работает криво.

**xml(анимация начинается в path_1):**

```
<animated-vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt">
    <aapt:attr name="android:drawable">
        <vector
            android:name="vector"
            android:width="100dp"
            android:height="50dp"
            android:viewportWidth="100"
            android:viewportHeight="50">
            <group android:name="group">
                <path
                    android:name="path_1"
                    android:fillColor="#ffffff"
                    android:pathData="M 11.039 1.105 L 88.707 1.105 C 91.358 1.105 93.904 2.159 95.778 4.034 C 97.653 5.909 98.707 8.454 98.707 11.105 L 98.707 38.628 C 98.707 40.383 98.245 42.108 97.367 43.628 C 96.49 45.148 95.227 46.411 93.707 47.288 C 92.187 48.166 90.462 48.628 88.707 48.628 L 11.039 48.628 C 8.388 48.628 5.843 47.574 3.968 45.699 C 2.094 43.825 1.039 41.279 1.039 38.628 L 1.039 11.105 C 1.039 8.454 2.094 5.909 3.968 4.034 C 5.843 2.159 8.388 1.105 11.039 1.105"
                    android:strokeWidth="1"
                    android:strokeColor="#000000" />
            </group>
        </vector>
    </aapt:attr>
    <target android:name="path_1">
        <aapt:attr name="android:animation">
            <set>
                <objectAnimator
                    android:duration="1000"
                    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
                    android:propertyName="strokeColor"
                    android:valueFrom="#000000"
                    android:valueTo="#ffdf00"
                    android:valueType="colorType" />
                <objectAnimator
                    android:duration="1000"
                    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
                    android:propertyName="strokeColor"
                    android:startOffset="1000"
                    android:valueFrom="#ffdf00"
                    android:valueTo="#000000"
                    android:valueType="colorType" />
            </set>
        </aapt:attr>
    </target>
</animated-vector>
```

Что пробовал:

- Добавить `android:ordering="sequentially"` и 
              `android:repeatMode="restart"` в `<set>`, эффекта нет.
- Добавить `android:ordering="sequentially"` и 
              `android:repeatMode="restart"` в `<set>`, убрав у второго `objectAnimation` атрибут `android:startOffset="1000"`. Привело к тому что анимации воспроизвелись одновременно и не повторились, вообще не понял как это сработало так.
- Добавлять `android:repeatCount = "-1"`. Добавление атрибута только в первый `objectAnimator` ведёт к тому что зацикливается первая часть анимации, добавление во второй `objectAnimator` ведёт к тому что зацикливается вторая часть. И вроде бы осталось только поставить `android:repeatCount = "-1"` в оба `objectAnimator`, но нифига: ставлю в оба и анимации начинают работать **одновременно**, хотя такого вроде как быть не должно из - за  `android:startOffset="1000"` во втором `objectAnimator`. Причём ничего не изменится, если добавить/ убрать `android:ordering="sequentially"` из `<set>`, что вообще вроде как абсурд.

Через код:

```
drawable.registerAnimationCallback(new Animatable2.AnimationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Drawable drawable) {
                drawable.start();
            }
        });
```

Просто не работает.

Как это зафиксить? Ответ наверняка на поверхности где - то.

Comment: Сработало, блин. Атрибута `fillAfter` почему - то нет в оф.доках по 
`Animation resources`. Отвечайте отдельным ответом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не знаю почему человек ответивший в комментах удалил ответ.

Сработало:

```
<set
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:ordering="sequentially">
```

и в обоих `ObjectAnimator`

```
android:repeatCount="infinite"
android:repeatMode="reverse"
```